# Where and how should I add this new 'non-rails-way' method in my Rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class

I've written a small method to query and retrieve from an MS SQL 2008 server and I am not sure where to put the code in my rails app.

**The scenario:**
I am writing a Ruby and Rails app with a connection to a legacy MS SQL 2008 server DB.
A lot is working as expected, which is nice.
For now I work off a copy of the legacy DB and I treat it as readonly.  It's big (7000+ tables some of which have over 40 million records).  I am using it 'as-is' and don't want to change any of the underlying schema.

I do want to extend some very server-specific functionality.  For instance, I make use of:

```
thing = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(my_query_string_here)
```

... and it works.  The result is an array that contains a hash and I can get to the relevant hash value by using:

```
thing[0][""]
```

... which works.

So, I thought I should write a method to make this easier and I wrote:

```
Class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.queryRDW(x)
    res=ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(x)
    ret=res.to_hash
    return ret[0][""]
  end
end
```

and put it in config/initializers/tool.rb  Unfortunately, webrick complains about the file during boot with the following cryptic error:

```
.../config/initializers/tool.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
```

I recognize that this is not an out-of-the-box rails-way of doing things, so please don't remind me.  (My struggles remind me often enough)

**My question:**
Where should I put this code so that I can invoke it from within a controller or a view in my rails app?  Does this need to be a new Class method or something else?

Many thanks!

**Addendum:**
I changed Class to class (doh!)
I moved tool.rb into lib/
I changed tool.rb to now be:

```
module Tool
  def self.queryRDW(x)
    res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(x)
    res.to_hash[0][""]
  end
end
```

but doing this in `app/views/stats.html.erb`

```
thing=queryRDW("mysql string")
```

gets me an 'undefined method error'

**Addendum 2**
I made the directory app/concerns and put tool.rb there.
When I use:

```
<%=queryRDW("myStringHere")%>
```

in:

```
app/views/stats.html.erb
```

I get:

```
undefined method `queryRDW' for #<#<Class:0x0000000378ccf8>:0x00000003c1ce58>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to lowercase the keyword `class` in line 1.

I'd also say that this class doesn't need to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` — and doesn't even really need to be a class — if it's simply a wrapper around `exec_query`. There's nothing "wrong" with this, but if you never intend to instantiate an object of this class, you could just create a simple utility module:

```
module Tool
  def self.queryRDW(x)
    res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(x)
    res.to_hash[0][""]
  end
end
```

You can save this file in a couple of places:

1. `lib/tool.rb`. If you're using Rails 3, you'll need to add (or uncomment) this line in `config/application.rb`:

   ```
   # config/application.rb
   config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
   ```
2. `app/concerns/tool.rb`. This will automatically be detected by Rails 3.

I generally use `app/concerns` for tools that are entirely application-specific and `lib` for utilities that I might reuse among several different applications.

Comment: omg.  Thanks.  That fixed the 'unexpected keyword_end' and webrick starts.  Now, when I try to invoke queryRDW in a view, I get undefined method `queryRDW' for #<#<Class:0x000000036b75d0>:0x00000003632718>  What syntax should I use?

Comment: I didn't see this comment until after I'd updated my answer. Can you edit your question and add the code in the view that's generating this error?

Comment: Done.  Thanks for helping me along here.

Comment: do I need a require statement somewhere now?  Can that be added to a view which is an .erb file ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot that Rails 3 no longer automatically loads files in `lib`. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: No problem.  I updated the Q again.  Still getting 'undefined method'

Comment: Got it.  I needed to use <%=Tool.queryRDW("myStringHere")%>  I will be wanting to write additional modules in this fashion, but I have to figure out the namespace some more to tidy it all up.  Thanks for your excellent help.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put this in `config/initializers`.  This seems like code you'd put in `app/models`.

The error you're getting is syntax related, so double check the syntax.

To answer your question more directly, though, it's acceptable to put this stuff in your model if it's model related (in other words, part of your business domain).  If it is something extraneous or orthogonal to your domain, I'd put it in `lib`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying the file tool.rb should be moved into app/models ?  With what syntax would you then invoke queryRDW() ?

Comment: Yes, that seems appropriate.  Also, if this class doesn't actually model a real Active Record table, I'd just make it a plain ruby object inside of `app/models`.  As far as how you'd invoke it, I'm not sure I understand the question... you'd deal with it like any other object.  Can you post some more detail on how you're trying to use it?

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I now gather that making this a class is probably not correct.  There is no Tool table or Tool object per se.

Comment: That doesn't mean there shouldn't be a Tool class.  It just doesn't have to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` to live in `app/models`.